# Comparing zip files

Tags: linux, shell-script, zip

We need to compare the contents in each of 2 .zip files we have.
Each .zip file has of different file extensions. Each .zip file also contains another .zip file and a couple of subdirectories.

We don't have the luxury to use `zipcomp` utility.
How do we compare all the files in the 2 zip files and display the identical files to `matching.txt` output file and non-identical files to `non-matching.txt` output file ?

The whole idea is to find out which files in one zip file, produced by a build, has changed/modified in another later build run.

Answer (score 4):

Command `unzip -lv file.zip` prints contents of the `file.zip`, including CRC32 of every file in the archive (get `unzip` for Windows at http://info-zip.org or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/)).

Having this, you can simply use

```
unzip -lv file1.zip > list1.txt
unzip -lv file2.zip > list2.txt
```

and compare contents of `list1.txt` vs `list2.txt` using utility like `diff` or `diffuse`. If you want more automated approach, you can write simple Perl or Python script to compare these listing files (hint - use Perl hash or Python dictionary on every file CRC32 that was printed by `unzip -lv`.

Comment: Hi mvp thanks for responding; its a linux platform we are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use and customize the open-source tool `comp_zip`, available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unzip-ada/) and [here](https://github.com/zertovitch/zip-ada), that compares two Zip archives without writing any extra file. All is done in memory. On Linux, all you need to do is `gprbuild -P zipada comp_zip`. The source is in the file `tools/comp_zip.adb`.